# помогите мне хватает логики

Tags: node.js

Создайте функцию t9, которая принимает два параметра - имя папки и файла и проверяет есть ли данный файл в папке. Функция должна возвращать true или false

```
 function t9(folder, file) {
        fs.readdirSync(folder,(err,data)=>{
            if (){
            }else{}
        })
    }
    
    console.log(t9('home6', 't1.txt'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `fs.existsSync(path.join(......))`

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно определиться, используете вы синхронные или асинхронные вызовы. Для синхронных вызовов не нужен колбек, они непосредственно возвращают значение. В вашем случае синхронная функция возвращает массив имён файлов, поэтому достаточно проверить его на наличие заданного имени:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

function t9(folder, file) {
  const fileNames = fs.readdirSync(folder);
  return fileNames.includes(file);
}

console.log(t9('.', 'test.js'));
```